# Emacs ediff, foreign character sets, and text file encodings

Tags: emacs, encoding

Whenever I use a character set in addition to latin in a text file (mixing Cyrillic and Latin, say), I usually choose utf-16 for the encoding. This way I can edit the file under OS X with either emacs or TextEdit.

But then ediff in emacs ceases to work. It says only that "Binary files this and that differ".

Can ediff be somehow made to work on text files that include foreign characters?

Comment: Another typical example is Windows registry editor exports using UTF-16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customize the variable `ediff-diff-options` and add the option `--text`.

```
(setq ediff-diff-options "--text")
```

#### Edit:

Ediff calls out to an external program, the GNU utility `diff`, to compute the differences; however, `diff` does not understand unicode, and sees unicode encoded files as binary files.  The option "--text" simply forces it to treat the input files as text files.  See the manual for GNU Diffutils: [Comparing and Merging Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/index.html); in particular [1.7 Binary Files and Forcing Text Comparisons](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Binary.html).

Comment: So simple? Nice, thanks. But would you care to elaborate? The manual only mentions '-w' as a possible value for ediff-diff-options. What is happening for ediff not to work before the setq and how does the setq change it?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It works fine. I just wanted to know what was happening.

Comment: thanks very much, it resolve my problem and I also found if you run ediff first, the value is not effect immediately, for ediff use ediff-actual-diff-options, so I exit emacs and run again, it is OK.

Comment: That did not work with Emacs 25.3.1 of SLES 15 SP2: The diff buffer still said: `Binary files ... and ... differ`. Even setting `ediff-custom-diff-options` did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you use utf-8 instead of utf-16.  utf-8 is the standard encoding in most of the Unix world, including Mac OS X, and it does not suffer from those problems.

Comment: A new test now suggests that TextEdit opens utf-8 files just fine. The last time I went through the encodings utf-16 was the rare one that was handled seamlessly by both emacs and TextEdit when a file has more than one character set. This is a few years ago already. Has TextEdit perhaps added support for utf-8 in the meantime?